# How to find $k[x_1,\dotso,x_n]/I$ concretely?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to know if there is a way to find $k[x_1,\dotso ,x_n]/I$ in specific cases. For example how can we find concretely the ring $\mathbb{C}[X]/(X^2+1)$? How does one mod out $(X^2+1)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "find"?

Comment: There are cases when one can find explicitly what the quotient ring $k[x_1,\dotso ,x_n]/I$ is. In the example above (I corrected it because it was wrong before) I know that the quotient ring is $\mathbb{C}[X^2, X^3+X]$. But I don't know how to arrive to that conclusion.

Comment: One way is to use Buchberger algorithm to get a Groebner basis for $I$. Then the possible remainders you can get for elimination with respect to $I$; a sort of long division, are representatives for the quotient. In the case of one variable, it is just to look at the remainders by the usual long division by the generator of the ideal.

Comment: The same general question about quotient rings has been asked before on math.SE. Use the search function.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. It is clearer now.

Comment: Find explicitly in what sense?

Comment: By "find explicitly" I mean to find a ring which is isomorphic to the quotient ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over $\;\Bbb C\;$ :

$$x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)\implies $$

$$\Bbb C[x]/(x^2+1)=\Bbb C[x]/((x-i)(x+i))\cong \Bbb C[x](x-i)\times \Bbb C[x]/(x+i)$$

Now just figure out what $\,\Bbb C[x]/(x\pm i)\;$ is...:P

Comment: user53970 admittedly gave a bad example, but I doubt he wanted to restrict himself to the $n=1$ case.

Comment: The OP is *explicitly* asking for this *explicit* example in the question...

Comment: The case n=1 is enough. I am looking at some examples (without explanations) and I wanted to understand how did the author find the explicit quotient rings. There are some examples in the case $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ like $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(1+XY)$ From the comments above I know about the Buchberger algorithm and I will try to use it. Are there elegant shortcuts in this case like in the case n=1?

Comment: DonAntonio, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Any time, @user53970 : it was a pleasure since sometimes this can be a rather tough task.